# ERROR: column reference “customer” is ambiguous

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

#### GOAL

Estou realizando um contador na coluna nome do host para todo cliente igual ao BRASILFOODS, única coisa que eu queria, era que ao lado da contagem aparecesse o nome BRASILFOODS

#### QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT(*) hostname, customer
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'BRASILFOODS' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
 ERROR: column reference "customer" is ambiguous
 Line: 1
```

Comment: Pelo visto existem colunas com o mesmo nome em suas tabelas. Coloque o prefixo com a tabela a que se refere o campo, como você já fez em sua cláusula ON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma coluna chamada `customer` nas duas tabelas envolvidas: `tb_get_gap` e `tb_get_customers`, então ele não sabe qual das duas deve pegar, você deve dar o nome completamente qualificado da coluna, por exemplo `tb_get_gap.customer`, da mesma forma que usou no `WHERE`.

Parece existir um outro problema porque não está agrupando os dados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: SELECT tb_get_gap.customer, COUNT(*) hostname
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'FLEURY' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'

Me retornou: 
 ERROR: column "tb_get_gap.customer" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Esse é outro erro que não está na sua pergunta, você está pegando dados com cardinalidade diferente, então uma coluna pega uma quantidade de dados e a outra pega outra precisaria normalizar isso e pegar tudo igual. PRa falar a verdade olhando melhor eu acho que toda sua *query* está errada, e sua pergunta deveria ter envolvido o que quer fazer para poder refazer para dar o resultado esperado.

Comment: Consegui, a query ficou assim: SELECT tb_get_gap.customer, COUNT(*) hostname
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_get_customers
ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_get_customers.cust_cmdb WHERE tb_get_customers.customer = 'FLEURY' and tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
GROUP BY tb_get_gap.customer;

Comment: Se deu o resultado que deseja, ok, esta é uma forma de fazer.

Comment: muito obrigado!